# "R" …Partial Least Squares Regression: pslr(...)

Tags: r

`plsr()` doesn't seem to work with a formula, but it works manually, why is that?

```
y = plsr(W, data = mydata)   # this doesn't work!
Error in formula[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

 > W
[1] "GDPperCapita ~ 1 + administ + culture + Euro"

y = plsr(GDPperCapita ~ 1 + administ + culture + Euro, data = mydata)  # …but this works!
```

PS: I have tried manipulating the variable, W, with `noquote()`, but this doesn't solve it either…   A solution would be very appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: do you use `W  <- as.formula("GDPperCapita ~ 1 + administ + culture + Euro")` ?

Comment: At the moment "W" is not a formula. It just sort of looks like a formula but a real formula would not have those flanking double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you…   Just out of interest, is it perfectly ok for me to use the "=" sign instead of "<-" in R?